# version control for the exe

Tags: c#, implementation

I developed a Winform application, but it's not fully tested or bug-free. Since my management wants me to implement it, I am implementing it... The application is in C# and the backend is an SQl server. If I give the exe to all 50 users each time I have to change the code or fix a bug I need to update the exe to all users.

I heard about a concept of putting the actual exe in the server and then giving dummy exes to the user which check for the updated exe each time when it is clicked. So that each time I need to update only the server exe.

Can anyone suggest  ideas or any reference to the above requirement?

Comment: Are these internal users? Can you just put it on a service like Dropbox?

Comment: You are able to make own your update system, or just use [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) method.

Comment: All are Internal users for outside users we are using through citrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar requirements for the company I work for.  We use Click Once to enable automatic updates to roll out to each user each time they launch the application (from the start menu).  This makes turn around time for bug fixing very easy and painless.

Click once is built into Visual Studio under a projects properties page (publish tab). What I usually do is to publish it to a share (with the appropriate permissions set) then point people to the share internally.

[image]

Here are a few good links:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)